# Are the __iter__() and iter(), and __next__() and next() same?

Tags: python

1. `__iter__()` and `iter()`:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
newl1 = map((lambda x: x*x*x), l1)
newl1 = newl1.__iter__()
print(newl1)
print(type(newl1))
```

The above code's output is:

```
<map object at 0x000001DF03D37B50>
<class 'map'>
```

`#-----------------------------------------------------------------------`

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
newl1 = map((lambda x: x*x*x), l1)
newl1 = iter(newl1)
print(newl1)
print(type(newl1))
```

The above code's output is also:

```
<map object at 0x000002129AD37B50>
<class 'map'>
```

2. `__next__()` and `next()`:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
newl1 = map((lambda x: x*x*x), l1)
newl1 = newl1.__next__()
print(newl1)
print(type(newl1))
```

The above code's output is:

```
1
<class 'int'>
```

`#-----------------------------------------------------------------------`

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
newl1 = map((lambda x: x*x*x), l1)
newl1 = next(newl1)
print(newl1)
print(type(newl1))
```

And the above code's output is also:

```
1
<class 'int'>
```

I am getting the same output, no matter which of the either I am using. And if these are not same, then where are they used specifically, where they can't be used interchangeably?

I have looked in the official documentation, asked ChatGPT and also looked for previously asked questions on stackoverflow but I couldn't find what I am looking for. Thank you for your time and efforts

Comment: The documentation of [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) states: "Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its `__next__()` method.".

Comment: @Jeppe No, it doesn't answer my question

Comment: @Matthias I still don't understand the difference between them. One is function, which calls the method but I looked on many websites and official documentation, and couldn't find any reference of them being the same

Comment: @IRONMAN, "*then what does all of these exactly do?*" - this is an excessive question, as the answer is obvious. The difference between them in call context: inner (instance) and outer (builtin function).

Comment: I'm confused by the title of this post. What is `__name__`? Did you mean to say `__next__`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest My question is that, they are giving same output when used interchangeably. So, where are they specifically used, where they can't be used interchangeably? What is the purpose of each of these?

Comment: @Blckknght It was a typo, my mistake

Comment: You use `next` and `iter` to call them from outside, and these functions use `__next__` and `__iter__` defined in a class. Yes, you can call `__next__`, but methods with two leading and trailing underscores are not meant to be called directly.

Answer (score 1):

`iter()` function will use `__iter__()` function in the class，

`next()` function will use `__next__()` function in the class,

you can define the `__iter__()` or `__next__()` by yourself.

document https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=all#iter

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=next#next

https://zoujiu.blog.csdn.net/article/details/132529031

```
class C:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.k = [1, 2]
        self.num = 0
        
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        if self.num < len(self.k):
            kk = self.k[self.num]
            self.num += 1
            return kk
 
it = iter(C(), )
ret = []
ret.append(next(it))
ret.append(next(it))
ret
[1, 2]
```

reference

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/iter

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but aren't `__iter__()` and `__next__()` are methods instead of functions, as you mention in your answer?

Comment: you can define it in the class,

Comment: Yes, they are methods, but a method is nothing else than a function that belongs to a class.